# Turning off activity and power leds on Raspberry Pi 3 running Debian (NOT RASPBIAN)

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 currently hosting a web server.
I'd like to turn off the activity leds, and power led as they consume energy for nothing.
How can I do this using debian ? Under Raspbian it's easy, but under Debian I found no way of doing this.

The image I am using is : https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/

Answer (score 0):

Check out question 6 on the FAQ.
https://raspi.debian.net/faq/

I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, it appears that on the Raspberry Pi 3B+ model, it is not possible to turn off the power led, it is possible to turn off the activity led `ACT` by using

```bsh
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/ACT/brightness
```

but unlinke on raspbian on other pis, the `PWR` led does not appear in `/sys/class/leds`.
Electrical tape it is then, sigh.