# Turn off LEDs of Fujitsu Futro S740 running Debian 11

Tags: debian, terminal

I am running a few servers and hosting a pi-hole on Debian 11 installed on a Fujitsu Futro S740. I would like to permanently turn off as much LEDs as possible. Currently, there are three LEDs active:

1. white - status led (I assume), front;
2. orange - activity led, back, indicating sth. associated with network/ethernet;
3. green - similar, flashes constantly.

Is there a terminal command to do this?

---

Sources for Raspberry Pi:
https://fuzzthepiguy.tech/disable-onboard-leds/, https://raspi.debian.net/faq/, and
[Turning off activity and power leds on Raspberry Pi 3 running Debian (NOT RASPBIAN)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629302/turning-off-activity-and-power-leds-on-raspberry-pi-3-running-debian-not-raspbi).

I. e., on a RasPi, link one suggests

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness > /dev/null
```

to turn off the power LED. Link two suggests

```
0 > /sys/class/leds/PWR/brightness
```

to do the same.

---

`find /sys/class/leds` outputs

```
/sys/class/leds
/sys/class/leds/input10::capslock
/sys/class/leds/input10::numlock
/sys/class/leds/input10::kana
/sys/class/leds/input10::scrolllock
/sys/class/leds/input10::compose
```

Btw, I did not find a way to disable LEDs via BIOS.

Comment: The user guide of Fujitsu Futro S740 describes the white LED at the front as a "power indicator", so it might well be hardwired and not controllable. The two LEDs at the back would seem to be the usual NIC link/speed/activity lights, and since there does not seem to be any entries for them in `/sys/class/leds/`, the NIC driver has no provisions for controlling them. A RasPi is specifically designed for Linux use and to be adaptable for various projects, so the ability to switch off the LEDs can be useful; the Futro S740 is designed to be used as a thin client only.

Comment: Better use a black adhesive tape ;) https://cdn.manomano.com/ruban-adhesif-americain-scotch-2000-3m-pvc-50mm-x-46m-gris-gris-P-2764199-8250381_1.jpg

Comment: How about desoldering them?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Check `/sys/class/leds` directory to see if you can control those LEDs, in which case a folder would exist.

Then to turn off the LEDs, simply do

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/<led>/brightness
```

---

Edit: There is no entry for the LEDs you want (courtesy new question edit), thus you cannot turn them off.

They are wired in the hardware and are essential hardware indicators, it's best to not touch them lest troubleshooting becomes harder later.

Comment: That is impossible... Also, since you edited question with extra details, it seems there seems to be no way to control them. Why do you want to turn off the LEDs though? They consume negligible power.